# Uploading files to an Apache server via SSH from macOS Terminal

Tags: ssh, terminal, scp

I've never used Unix shell before and I'm trying to learn. Currently I'm stuck in a pretty basic command to upload files to an Apache (OpenSSH) server. I've been looking for an answer for days but I can't find a solution for this particular issue I'm having.

I login to the server using macOS Terminal and then I'm using this command to upload a file from my desktop to a directory in the server:

```
scp /Users/carlos/Desktop/test.html username@server:/home/username/server/wp-content/themes/
```

I get an error telling me that the test.html file doesn't exist:

```
/Users/carlos/Desktop/test.html: No such file or directory
```

I know the file exists and the path is right (I dragged and dropped the file into the Terminal window to make sure). Also I can open the file on VIM using the same path, so it's there.

I can't understand why I'm getting this error.

Can someone point me in the right direction to solve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks @RuiFRibeiro I got this: `/Users/carlos
-rw-r--r--@  1 carlos  staff     4 Feb 10 11:37 test.html`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro any idea on what could be causing this? I’m totally lost. Is the command I’m using right? File permissions are also OK right?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro did `cat /Users/carlos/Desktop/test.html`and nothing happened.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro no error… file size is 4 bytes (it's just an html that says test inside)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro this is what I'm seeing: https://snag.gy/EPXa4z.jpg

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro and no, I didn't lost power after creating the file

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro That worked, so I should upload the files before login to the server then… Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Got an answer in the comments from @RuiFRibeiro that solved my problem. Posting it here in case this helps someone else:

Since the scp file is copying a local file and the other side is a remote server command should be run on the Mac side, not the server.

So first I went to the directory my local file was in:

```
$ cd /Users/carlos/Desktop
```

and then I uploaded it to the server:

```
$ scp test.html username@server:/home/username/server/wp-content/themes/
```